# Correct link to storage in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display avatar in my page but I do not know how to do it. Look, here's my script. It doesn't work. Can you help me?

```
@foreach($user->user_data as $data)

 <img alt="" src="{{ asset('/storage/uploads/avatars/ {{ $data->avatar }} ') }}">

@endforeach
```

Comment: You will need to supply much more information and code than that for anyone to begin helping accurately. But at first glance... you are missing a lot of proper php for echoing out html.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, code inside `{{ }}` will be interpreted as php code, You can Try this One :

```
@foreach($user->user_data as $data)

   <img alt="" src="{{ asset('/storage/uploads/avatars/'. $data->avatar) }}">

@endforeach
```

It's like you do:

```
<img alt="" src="<?php echo asset('/storage/uploads/avatars/'. $data->avatar); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `storage_path` helper in laravel. Try using this:

```
@foreach($user->user_data as $data)

  <img alt="" src="{{ storage_path('uploads/avatars/' . $data->avatar) }}">

@endforeach
```

Link to the doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-storage-path

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Laravel the normal way you can't link to the storage folder directly because it's located outside of the public folder.

Only the contents of the public folder are accessible to the outside world.

There are two ways to work around this limitation, depending on how sensitive the stored data is.

- If anyone may access the file, the easiest solution is to create a symlink from inside your public folder to the avatar storage folder.
- If the file needs to be protected, create a Controller class that authorises the user and then returns the desired data from the storage_path.

In your case it sounds like solution 1 would suffice, and fortunately for you Laravel has built-in support for this.

By executing the following command in your command line Laravel will create a symbolic link from public/storage to storage/public:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

You can then create a link to anything that is stored in storage/public by using the asset function

```
asset('storage/path_relative_to_storage_public')
```

For a more detailed explanation, see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#the-public-disk